# Animating changing a CSS value with pure JS

Tags: javascript

Ok so I'm changing the value of the CSS 'left' property, like so:

```
s_list.style.left = left - amount + 'px';
```

s_list is a variable which is a UL element. This line gets executed on click of a button. But the effect is instant, to fast to see any sort of animation left. Is there anything i can do with pure JS to slow this down or add a configurable delay to the change?

To see my working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/benhowdle89/RCkPq/

And possibly suggest a solution!

Comment: If you want it to occur over time, use setTimeout and move it incrementally.

Comment: @kinakuta - Or `requestAnimationFrame` to be more efficient. ;)

Comment: @Derek looks interesting, although looks a little too new to be practical yet

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question (well, in fact is a comment ;) ), but If could use the CSS transition, it could be easer. Of course it depends by the browser you have to support. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions also for the supported browsers.

Comment: @ZER0 - Probably 10 years later Microsoft Internet Explorer 42 will support CSS3 transition. :/

Comment: @Derek IE10 seems support them. :) As I said, it depends by the browsers have to be supported (e.g. if you're in an intranet environment or you're doing some browser's extension, and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic animation, you can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. However, in modern browsers they are outdated. A more efficient way to animate things around is by using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame).

```
function animate(things){
    //Do stuff here.
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

You might ask, `"How is this different?"` Well, `requestAnimationFrame` will only redraw the screen only when the user can actually see the element. If the user is on another tab, or scrolled down the page, it won't redraw it. It saves *memories* in the computer.

Unfortunately, until now every browser still need a prefix. Here's a [fix](https://gist.github.com/838785):

```
if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {
        return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  //webkit
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||            //mozilla
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||              //opera
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||             //IE!
        function(callback, element) {
            window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 ); //not supported
        };
    } )();
}
```

## UPDATED

**LIVE DEMOS:**

1. [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/)
2. [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/4/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/4/) - Cycle through images <sub><sup>***(Still no jQuery!)***</sup></sub>

Comment: As far as compatibility goes, it seems like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is probably still the way to go.

Comment: No way! That's really cool. Any idea why it keeps skipping back to the first image, is it possible at all to cycle through the images...

Comment: @benhowdle89 - Do you mean it keeps going and going and going?

Comment: Yeah so, if you keep clicking "NEXT" it just keeps going through all the images...

Comment: @benhowdle89 - Do you want to use jQuery? It will help out on this kind of stuff. (Especially on modifying the DOM)

Comment: I'd love to use jQuery :) But I'm curious if I/people can do it using pure JS

Comment: You want me to make a demo for you?

Comment: @benhowdle89 - Voila! Not using jQuery animation! http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/3/

Comment: @benhowdle89 - UPDATED. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4wLsC/4/ Did not use jQuery at all.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is immediately change the value to it's final position at the click.

In order to animate, you need to iterate over a longer time, changing the left value by a little fraction of the amount every frame.

Try using `setInterval` or a chain of `setTimeout`'s, in which every step moves the element by a few pixels, in order to achieve an animation.

example:

```
function move(){
   s_list.style.left = s_list.style.left - amount/10 + 'px';
   if (s_list.style.left.slice(0, -2) > desired_offset){
      setTimeout(move,10);
   }
}
```

this moves the element by amount/10 pixels, and repeats the action until you've reached the desired location. the amount/10 can be changed to any rate/speed you want.

**EDIT:** added .slice for string/num comparison (credit: Wex)

**Double EDIT**: listen to Wex in the comments below.

Comment: You'll probably need to do some kind of String[.slice(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)0, -2) to do your String and Number comparisons.

Comment: Ahh yes, attention to details isn't my strong side.

Comment: You could also improve this solution by storing the intermediate value of `s_list.style.left = s_list.style.left - amount/10` in a temporary variable, and if it is larger than the desired offset you would make the current value equal to the temporary value; else make the current value equal to the desired offset (so you don't have any overflow).

Comment: What are you seeing as desired_offset as?

Comment: This depends on what you are doing? according to your fiddle you want the dog picture to change to the cat picture. it seems that left = -540 is what you need to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`setInterval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to run your code periodically.

Or just [use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Pure JS seems to imply no external libraries such as jQuery.

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the question.  I'll leave the link for other people.